# Update two different columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I had a table named 
dbo.stocks columns sid ,stocks
Values (1,150),(2,200),(3,300)
I had another table called 
dbo.purchase columns pid,purchaee
Values (1,100),(2,150),(4,400)

I need to update add stocks column with purchase column with matching SID and PID and if I don't find any match with the ids column then that row from purchase should be inserted into stocks column

My result should be like this
SID stocks
1   250
2   350
3   300
4   400

Comment: What have you tried? You have to use simple join to get joined data from stocks and purchases. Why is sql-server and mysql tagged? I think this is only SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming : You have inserted in purchase table and you have the key ...

you can do insert or update in a single query like this :

```
INSERT INTO stocks (id, value) VALUES(1, 100) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
value=100
```

Refer to the documentation here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html